# Spivak chapter 5 exercise 36 - prove $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(1/x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

There're similar questions already, but I somewhat struggled to apply their reasoning to this particular statement.

I wanted to ask if my proof is correct (and clarify several things which I've seemingly figured out when writing it here). Here's the proof:

$$\mbox{(1) }\lim_{x \to 0^-} f\left(\frac1x\right)=l \mbox{ if } \forall\varepsilon>0(\exists\delta>0(\forall x(0<0-x<\delta \longrightarrow|f\left(\frac1x\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$

$$\mbox{(2) }\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=m \mbox{ if } \forall\varepsilon>0(\exists N(\forall x(x<N \longrightarrow|f(x)-m|<\varepsilon$$

We need to show that $l=m$.

from (1) we have
$$-\delta>x>0\longrightarrow|f\left(\frac1x\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$

let $g(x)=f\left(\frac1x\right)$, then we have
$$-\delta>x>0\longrightarrow|g\left(x\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$

in (2) we suppose that $x<N$. Hence $\frac1x>\frac1N$. Let $x'=\frac1x$. Furthermore, since $-\delta$ is negative and we can assume that $N$ is negative. (If it's not, we can take $N$ to be -1 or any other negative number, because if the conclusion holds $\forall x<N$, it surely holds for a subset $(-\infty,-1)$). We can take $-\delta=\frac1N$, which gives us

$$\frac1N=-\delta<x'<0$$ and this is the hypothesis from (1). Hence we conclude that

$$|g\left(x'\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$ or $$|f\left(\frac1{\frac1x}\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$ or $$|f\left(x\right)-l|<\varepsilon$$

To summarise, $x<N\longrightarrow|f\left(x\right)-l|<\varepsilon$. By the definition of the limit $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=l$$ but also $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=m$$ Therefore $l=m$.

Comment: With these limit expressions instead of saying "$\forall\varepsilon>0(\exists\delta$..." it's probably better to say "for each [any] $\varepsilon$...". The former implies that we can find a **single** $\delta$ that will work **for all** $\varepsilon$'s, which is generally not true. You probably already know this. I sometimes write "for all" without thinking about it. The ambiguity of natural english language can mess us up :)

Comment: There appears to be a sign mistake going from "$0<0-x<\delta$" to "$-\delta>x>0$"

Comment: @Ben single  that will work for all 's would be $\exists \delta \forall \epsilon$. But the other way around means for every single $\epsilon$ we can find a $\delta$ which shouldn't be the same. What mistake do you think is in the inequality? I multiplied it by -1.

Comment: It looks like you maybe forgot to switch the sign for $0$, for example, $x$ and $-x$ both seem to be $>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WA Don nailed it, but I feel compelled to add an answer.

I'm going through Spivak myself and when first encountering problems like this, I tried approaches very similar to super.t's.

It took a while to absorb what was going on. Initially I found it a bit confusing trying to keep straight which conditions are fixed, which can vary, and what implies what.

Here I'll rework the problem, annotating with a few comments. The aim is to hopefully help clarify the thinking behind the approach. Apologies for stating things that may seem obvious to you, and generally for over-explaining. Hopefully this is of some use to someone, someday.

Show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f\left(\frac1x\right)= \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$$

We can see intuitively that this makes sense: as $x$ gets very small negative on the left hand side, $1/x$ becomes very large negative, and the 2 sides both look like $f$ of some very large negative number.

Let's assume that the first limit exists, and is equal to $\ell$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f\left(\frac1x\right)= \ell$$

If this is true, then from the definition of the limit at $0$ from below, we have: for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, if

$$0 < -x < \delta, \text{then} \left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

or, multiplying the $\delta$ expression by $-1$, we have for all $x$, if
$$0 > x > -\delta, \text{then} \left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

Let's pause for a moment and consider what this says. Here, $x$ is just some number. This says that, if we have some number between $0$ and $-\delta$, then $f(\frac{1}{\text{number}})$ will be "sufficiently close" to $\ell$.

Let's try sticking $1/y$ in as "number". The motivation for this choice is that we have an expression involving $\left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \ell \right\vert$ and we'd like to instead have an expression for $f(x)$. Sticking $1/y$ into the above expression for $x$ we have

$$\text{If } 0 > 1/y > -\delta \text{ then } \left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{(1/y)}\right) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$
or
$$\left\vert f(y) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

Again, the original $x$ expression was true for all numbers $x$ that satisfied the $\delta$ condition on the left hand side, so this new expression for $f(y)$ is true for all numbers $1/y$ that satisfy $0 > 1/y > -\delta$.

Now if $0 > 1/y > -\delta$, what does this tell us about $y$?

Multiplying by $-1$ to make everything nonegative, to avoid any sign confusion:

$$0< -1/y < \delta$$
Inverting
$$0<1/\delta<-y$$

Finally, multiplying again by $-1$ we have
$$0 > -1/\delta > y$$

Let's summarize what this all implies:

We know that if the first limit exists, then for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for all $y$ if
$$y < -1/\delta \text{ then } \left\vert f(y) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

Or, substituting $N = -1/\delta$ we have, **for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $N<0$ such that for all $y$, if
$$y < N \text{ then } \left\vert f(y) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$**

Another way of writing this is:
$$\lim_{y \to -\infty} f(y) = \ell$$

Thus, if the first limit exists, then so too does the second, and they are equal.

**A key point here is the equivalence of the conditions $y < -1/\delta < 0$ and $0 > 1/y > -\delta$.** The first implies the second and vice versa.

**Finally to complete the proof, we can begin with the second limit and similarly show that if it exists, then so too does the first, and they are equal.**

The steps will be very similar to what we've already done.

**Alternate justification for substituting in $y = 1/x$**

Going back to the beginning, we see that the first limit involves $f(1/x)$. What do the $\delta$-restrictions tell us about $1/x$?

If the first limit is $\ell$ then, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if
$$0 < -x < \delta, \text{then} \left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

If
$$0 < -x < \delta$$
then
$$0 < 1/\delta <\frac{1}{-x}$$ or
$$0 > -1/\delta >\frac{1}{x}$$

Thus, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $N = -1/\delta < 0$ such that for all $x$, if
$$\frac{1}{x}< N \text{ then } \left\vert f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \ell \right\vert < \varepsilon$$

We can see here we're almost to the second limit. We just need to replace the number $\frac{1}{x}$ with $x$ (or $y$, or any other name).

Comment: Such a great answer. Very well explained about sticking $\frac1y$ into the hypothesis of (1), it was the most difficult part for me.

Comment: I'm glad if it's at all helpful! This same "sticking in some number" trick can be used, for example, to demonstrate the equivalence of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h)$, an exercise Spivak suggests in the text but leaves to the reader. Worth returning to once you better know what he's up to.

Answer (score 3):

The proof you give becomes a bit unwieldy and it does not make clear that $N$ must be negative.

I think it can be shortened as follows:

---

Assume $\lim_{x\to0^-} f(1/x)$ exists and equals $\ell$.  Then take any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Because the limit above exists, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\lvert f(1/x) - \ell\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon \text{ for all } -\delta \leqslant x < 0. \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Now take any $y \leqslant -1/\delta$, write $x=1/y$.  It follows $-\delta \leqslant x < 0$.  This satisifies the criterion in \eqref{eq1}, so $\lvert f(1/x)-\ell \rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$, which is the same as $\lvert f(y) - \ell\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$.

Thus for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $m$ (taking $m=1/\delta$) such that $\lvert f(y)-\ell\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ whenever $y \leqslant -m$. This provbes $\lim_{y\to-\infty}f(y)$ exists and equals $\ell$.

Comment: I might replace $\delta \geqslant 0$ with $\delta > 0$. Same for the other $\geqslant$'s and $\leqslant$'s though those are equivalent to $>$ and $<$ so no real harm done.

Comment: You are right.  I have corrected it.  Thanks